# How to understand such stack trace from Google Play app?

Tags: android, crash, stack-trace

On Google Play developer console I sometimes get crash reports that I don't understand at all. There is noting from my app code in the stack trace reported. Could anyone shed some light e.g. on this one?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1338)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1286)
at android.speech.tts.ITextToSpeechService$Stub$Proxy.setCallback(ITextToSpeechService.java:573)
at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$Connection.onServiceConnected(TextToSpeech.java:1278)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1125)
at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1142)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

It's clearly in some Text to Speech package, but how am I, the app author, resposible for this one? I do initialize TTS and my app is reading text aloud, but how can I fix such error?

Greg

Comment: I haven't done much with TTS. Are you supplying an `Intent`, `PendingIntent`, or `Bundle` to it? If so, what's in the `Bundle` (or `Intent` extras)? In particular, are you trying to use your own `Parcelable` classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is your errors

```
ITextToSpeechService$Stub$Proxy.setCallback(ITextToSpeechService.java:573)
```

it's clearly !

Comment: Thank you, @H4F, there may be something in it... I my code I call: myTTS.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(getCurrentService()); where the service object also implements the TTS callback. So apparently there is a very rare case where the service is not created or destroyed and still something is trying to call me back... Much appreciate your help!

Comment: Still don't understand why this happened on someone's device, but added some safeguards against service object being null, making sure TTS speech is stopped if the service is destroyed etc. Will see if that helps... Thanks again!